# Hardware video encoding with ffmpeg

Tags: video-encoding

I need to compress Full HD videos with ffmpeg with normal pc hardware.

Encoding should be some sort of H.264 or Mp4 (quality wise).

What hardware do I need for fast encoding times? Is a good CPU or GPU better? How important is RAM?

Are there any benchmarks?

Comment: What exactly is your question? As always with hardware: the better the better. Also benchmarks for what?

Comment: Video encoding is a CPU job. The GPU plays no role. A CPU with 4 GHz and 8 cores would do a good job. Lots of RAM always helps. I use a desktop with 8GB and an Intel i7 with good results. Laptop CPUs will be slower.